# Database Constraints for Date Range - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, date, constraints

I would like to check if there is some type of database constraint that satisfies the following use case, based on the simplified entity-relationship diagram below:

[image]

- A course can have one or more disciplines
- A discipline can be part of one or more courses

We then have a many-to-many relationship. To ensure that no discipline is inserted more than once for the same course, a composite key formed by the primary keys of the course and discipline tables is created.

However, a discipline can be part of more than one course. The only restriction is that your start date, end date, or both (in this particular case, I'm not taking into account which day of the week, just the start and end dates) cannot overlapping the start date and end date of previously registered course and discipline.

Examples:

Course
1  System Analysis
2  Information System

Discipline
1  Programming Logic
2  Data Structure

Class
1  1  07/01/2023  12/10/2023  // System Analysis - Programming Logic
1  2  07/02/2023  12/11/2023  // System Analysis - Data Structure
2  1  06/01/2023  11/10/2023  // Information System - Programmin Logic

The last register of "class" table must raise a constraint, since the end date fall within the date range of first register (primary-key 1 1).

So, how to prevent this using constraint ? Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.